# Searching Error in Linq when checking for nulls

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I have a code like this:

```
var organisations = Uow.Query<Organisation>()
                       .Where(x => x.PersonOrganisationRoles.Any(por =>
                           por.Person.FirstName != null &&
                           por.Person.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchFragmentLower)));
```

So there is a bridging table between Organisation Person and Role. This query is trying to find orgs that have people with a FirstName containing the string.

The problem is when I run it I get:

> Cannot use Person[FirstName <> NULL] as part of a logical expression in an Any or All expression

How can I check for `null`?

Comment: is `phr` suppose to be `por` in `phr.Person.FirstName.ToLower().
Contains(searchFragmentLower)`

Answer (score 2):

did you try `por => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(por.Person.FirstName)`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is complaining about the SQL that Linq is generating

try moving the null check into a where clause before running the any

```
var organisations = Uow.Query<Organisation>().
Where(x => x.PersonOrganisationRoles.Where(por => por != null && por.Person != null && por.Person.FirstName != null).Any(por => phr.Person.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchFragmentLower)));
```